# iOS: Custom button not showing on Storyboard

Tags: ios, button, interface, storyboard, builder

I am displaying an image programatically in my storyboard and handling successfully landscape/portrait orientation (see code below). I'm trying now to add a custom button on that same view in the storyboard via Interface Builder directly. The button just does not show up when the app runs. Only the image. Could you show me the way to do it on the storyboard view? Or should I add it programatically as well? Or redo everything 100% in Interface builder? Don't really know how to mix and match these 2 methods...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];



    UIImage *startImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"title.png"];
    UIImageView *startImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:startImage];

    self.startImageView = startImageView;

    [self.view addSubview:startImageView];


}

- (void) orientStartImageView
{
     UIInterfaceOrientation curOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
     if (curOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || curOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
     [self.startImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(-128, 0, 1024, 1024)];
 }else{
     [self.startImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -128, 1024, 1024)];
 }
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self orientStartImageView];
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    [self orientStartImageView];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its bcoz you are adding ImageView on top of the Button, you can bring it to front using this code, put it in `viewdidload` method :

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourBtn];
```

Comment: thanks. I was actually wondering how would the app handle ordering of images.

Comment: [self.view insertSubview:<#(UIView *)#> aboveSubview:<#(UIView *)#>];
    [self.view insertSubview:<#(UIView *)#> atIndex:<#(NSInteger)#>];
    [self.view insertSubview:<#(UIView *)#> belowSubview:<#(UIView *)#>];